# Progress bar in data.table aggregate action

Tags: r, data.table

`ddply` has a `.progress` to get a progress bar while it's running, is there an equivalent for `data.table` in R?

Comment: Do you mean a progress bar for `fread()`? If so, check `verbose` parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use any progress status you want.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a=1:4, b=c("a","b"))
dt[, {cat("group:",b,"\n"); sum(a)}, b]
#group: a 
#group: b 
#   b V1
#1: a  4
#2: b  6
```

If you ask about progress in loading csv file with `fread` then it will automatically be displayed for bigger datasets. Also as mentioned by Sergey in comment you can use `verbose` argument to get more information, both in `fread` and in `[.data.table`.

If you want the percentage of groups processed.

```
grpn = uniqueN(dt$b)
dt[, {cat("progress",.GRP/grpn*100,"%\n"); sum(a)}, b]
#progress 50 % 
#progress 100 % 
#   b V1
#1: a  4
#2: b  6
```

Answer (score 4):

Following up on @jangorecki's excellent answer, here's a way to use a text progress bar:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a=1:4, b=c("a","b"))
grpn = uniqueN(dt$b)
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = grpn, style = 3)
dt[, {setTxtProgressBar(pb, .GRP); Sys.sleep(0.5); sum(a)}, b]
close(pb)
```

Answer (score 3):

Following up on @jangorecki and other great answers, you can use the data.table symbol .NGRP instead of calculating grpn as in the other answers:

```
dt[, {cat("progress",.GRP/.NGRP*100,"%\n"); sum(a)}, b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Following up again on @jangorecki's great answer.

If you don't want to spam your terminal too much, you can make an external function equivalent to jangorecki's, but which does a modulus check and only prints if .GRP is divisible by a certain number "mod". Note, using the if function within the data.table curly-brackets itself doesn't work, which I assume is because if function's in R also use curly brackets.

```
progress = function(.GRP, grpn, mod) {
  if(!(.GRP %% mod)) {
  cat("progress", .GRP/grpn*100,"%\n")
  }
}
```

Then do. Here I use mod = 1000, so it would only print the percentage every 1000 groups.

```
dt[, {progress(.GRP, grpn, 1000); sum(a)}, b]
```