# Combine unique rows from multiple data.tables and add attribute details

Tags: r, data.table, rbindlist

I have two data.tables in this format (the actual tables have about a million rows in each):

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(
  code=c("A001", "A002","A003","A004","A005"),
  x=c(65,92,25,450,12), 
  y=c(98,506,72,76,15),
  no1=c(010101, 010156, 028756, 372576,367383),
  no2=c(876362,"",682973,78269,"")
)


dt2 <- data.table(
  code=c("A003", "A004","A005","A006","A007","A008","A009"),
  x=c(25,126,12,55,34,134,55), 
  y=c(72,76,890,568,129,675,989),
  no1=c(028756, 372576,367383,234876, 287156, 123348, 198337),
  no2=c(682973,78269,65378,"","","",789165)
)
```

I would like to combine the two together and keep only unique rows based on all column entries being unique. This is what I have but I assume there is a better way of doing it:

```
dt3 <- rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2))
dt3 <- unique(dt3, by = c("code", "x", "y", "no1", "no2"))
```

Once I have this single dataset I would like to give any duplicate 'code' records some attribute information (version number and a comment about what's different in that version to the previous one). The output I am looking for would be this:

```
dt4 <- data.table(
  code=c("A001", "A002","A003","A004","A005", "A004","A005","A006","A007","A008","A009"),
  x=c(65,92,25,450,12,126,12,55,34,134,55), 
  y=c(98,506,72,76,15,76,890,568,129,675,989),
  no1=c(010101, 010156, 028756, 372576,367383, 372576,367383,234876, 287156, 123348, 198337),
  no2=c(876362,"",682973,78269,"",78269,65378,"","","",789165),
  version = c("V1","V1","V1","V1","V1","V2","V2","V1","V1","V1","V1"),
  unique_version=c("A001_V1", "A002_V1","A003_V1","A004_V1","A005_V1", "A004_V2","A005_V2","A006_V1","A007_V1","A008_V1","A009_V1"),
  comment = c("First_entry","First_entry","First_entry","First_entry","First_entry","New_x", "New_y_and_no2","First_entry","First_entry","First_entry","First_entry")
  )
```

I'm not sure how to achieve `dt4` (and in an efficient way considering the size of the real dataset will be over a million rows).

**Edit**

Having applied @Chase's solution to my real data I noticed my dt3 example varies slightly from the type of result I am getting. This looks more like my real data:

```
dt6 <- data.table(
  code=c("A111", "A111","A111","A111","A111", "A111","A111","A234", "A234","A234","A234","A234", "A234","A234"),
  x=c("",126,126,"",836,843,843,126,126,"",127,836,843,843), 
  y=c("",76,76,"",456,465,465,76,76,"",77,456,465,465),
  no1=c(028756, 028756,028756,057756, 057756, 057756, 057756,028756, 028756,057756,057756, 057756, 057756, 057756),
  no2=c("","",034756,"","","",789165,"",034756,"","","","",789165)
)

comp_cols <- c("x", "y", "no1", "no2")

#grabs the names of the mismatching values and formats them how you did
f <- function(x,y) {
  n_x <- names(x)
  diff <- x != y
  paste0("New_", paste0(n_x[diff], collapse = "_and_"))
}


dt6[, version := paste0("V", 1:.N), by = code]
dt6[, unique_version := paste(code, version, sep = "_")]
dt6[, comment := ifelse(version == "V1", "First_entry", f(.SD[1], .SD[2])), by = code, .SDcols = comp_cols]
```

As you can see the suggested solution to create the comment column seems to be returning only the first change between the first and second versions (and not the changes better V2 and V3 etc.)

Comment: Do you always only have two versions or are there 3+?

Comment: There are more than two. Sorry, I didn't make that clear. My edited question has a better representation of what my real data looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution - the first two are trivial, the comment takes a little more thought:

```
dt5 <- copy(dt3)

comp_cols <- c("x", "y", "no1", "no2")

#grabs the names of the mismatching values and formats them how you did
f <- function(x,y) {
  n_x <- names(x)
  diff <- x != y
  paste0("New_", paste0(n_x[diff], collapse = "_and"))
}


dt5[, version := paste0("V", 1:.N), by = code]
dt5[, unique_version := paste(code, version, sep = "_")]
dt5[, comment := ifelse(version == "V1", "First_entry", f(.SD[1], .SD[2])), by = code, .SDcols = comp_cols]
```

End up yielding this:

```
> dt5
    code   x   y    no1    no2 version unique_version      comment
 1: A001  65  98  10101 876362      V1        A001_V1  First_entry
 2: A002  92 506  10156             V1        A002_V1  First_entry
 3: A003  25  72  28756 682973      V1        A003_V1  First_entry
 4: A004 450  76 372576  78269      V1        A004_V1  First_entry
 5: A005  12  15 367383             V1        A005_V1  First_entry
 6: A004 126  76 372576  78269      V2        A004_V2        New_x
 7: A005  12 890 367383  65378      V2        A005_V2 New_y_andno2
 8: A006  55 568 234876             V1        A006_V1  First_entry
 9: A007  34 129 287156             V1        A007_V1  First_entry
10: A008 134 675 123348             V1        A008_V1  First_entry
11: A009  55 989 198337 789165      V1        A009_V1  First_entry
```

Comment: Thanks @Chase. However, I made a mistake with my initial example data. The edited question contains a better representation of my actual dataset. The other issue my real dataset contains 5.5 million rows and therefore takes a number of hours to process. Is there any way of adding a progress bar (similar to what is proposed here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129223/progress-bar-in-data-table-aggregate-action) to help?