# Identify the difference between rows in data.table and create new column saying what the differences are

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset that looks likes this:

```
Data01 <- data.table(
  code=c("A111", "A111","A111","A111","A111", "A111","A111","A234", "A234","A234","A234","A234", "A234","A234"),
  x=c("",126,126,"",836,843,843,126,126,"",127,836,843,843), 
  y=c("",76,76,"",456,465,465,76,76,"",77,456,465,465),
  no1=c(028756, 028756,028756,057756, 057756, 057756, 057756,028756, 028756,057756,057756, 057756, 057756, 057756),
  no2=c("","",034756,"","","",789165,"",034756,"","","","",789165)
)

Data01[, version := paste0("V", 1:.N), by = code]
Data01[, unique_version := paste(code, version, sep = "_")]
```

What I would like is a way of adding a column that for each unique `code` entry says what the difference between each row and the previous one is (i.e. pasting the column name(s) where there are now different values). Something like this:

```
Data01[, change := c("First_entry","New_x_and_y","New_no2","New_x_and_y_and_no_1","New_x_and_y","New_x_and_y","New_no2","First_entry","New_no2","New_x_and_y_and_no1","New_x_and_y","New_x_and_y","New_x_and_y","New_no2")]
```

My actual dataset has 5.5 million rows and around 2.6 million unique `code` entries so I would imagine any solution to this would take some time to complete. It would therefore really helpful to include some sort of progress indicator (like something suggested here: [Progress bar in data.table aggregate action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129223/progress-bar-in-data-table-aggregate-action)) if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
nm <- c("x","y","no1","no2") #names(Data01)[-1L]
Data01[, change := c("First_entry", 
        sapply(seq_len(.N)[-1L], function(n) {
            paste(c("New", 
                nm[which(unlist(.SD[n-1L]) != unlist(.SD[n]))]), 
                collapse="_")
        })), 
    by=.(code)]
```